# How to find a record in DataSet?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dataset

I'm trying to find a specific record in a `Dataset`, this is filled by a results of a query, for example:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM tax ORDER BY id"
MyAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, my connection string here)
MyAdapter.Fill(ds)
```

Now I've another `Dataset` with the content of the same table but of another database. I'm trying to get the field `hash`, this allow me to compare all the fields of the row of this `hash`. Actually what I did is create a loop like this:

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

   Dim x As Integer = 0

   For x = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

       Dim local_hash = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item("hash")
       Dim web_hash = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item("hash") 'This is another dataset as I explained in the comment above.

       If local_hash = web_hash 'compare if the hash is equal
```

Now this code doesn't work for a obvious reason, the index of the two database are different in the loop then I'll never find the `hash` field referring to the index of the loop on the dataset. So I want to ask if there is a method like `.Find` or something else that I can use for avoid this situation.

Comment: Don´t you have a primary key in your table?

Comment: `find` by what? what will be your key to use `find`?

Comment: As I said I want find the field "hash" in the web dataset called ds2. And @AlexB. I've a PK but it's a sync tool so I have GUID

Comment: So you have two databases with synced data but different GUID Primary Keys?

Comment: outside loop `Dim view as New DataView(ds2.Tables(0),"", "hash", CurrentRows)`. Inside loop `view.Find({ds.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item("hash")})`

Comment: http://fromdual.com/how_to_setup_mysql_master-slave_replication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select from a `DataTable` to get an array of rows matching criteria:

```
Dim dtLocal = ds.Tables(0)
Dim dtWeb = ds2.Tables(0)

Dim local_hash As String  '??
Dim search As String = "Hash = '{0}'"
For n = 0 To dtLocal.Rows.Count-1

    local_hash = dtLocal.Rows(n).Item("hash").ToString

    ' get matching rows 
    Dim webRows = dtWeb.Select(String.Format(search, local_hash))

    'iterate matches
    For Each r As DataRow In webRows
        ' do wonderful things
    Next

Next
```

You may have to play with the search string format since it is not clear what the hash is.  Sounds like string.

---

An alternative would be to use a `DataView` or yet another would be to use one `DataTable` as a "master" and rebuild the other one using the "hash" of the current row as a SQL WHERE clause.  The DataView version from comments would look like this:

```
Dim dvW As New DataView(dtWeb, "", "hash", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
For n = 0 To dtLocal.Rows.Count - 1
    local_hash = dtLocal.Rows(n).Item("hash").ToString

    ' get matching rows 
    Dim webRows = dvW.FindRows(local_hash)

    ' iterate matches
    ' possibly panic if more than one row
    For Each dvr As DataRowView In webRows
        ' do wonderful things
    Next
Next
```

If you use `Find` instead of `FindRows`, it will return the index of the row.  FindRows would catch other problems such as a Guid/hash used more than once.

---

Using 400+ "master" rows and 4000+ "detail" rows, and just iterating the master to collect the details IDs, each takes about the same amount of time: 260ms for `DataTable.Select` vs 376 to recreate the table entirely vs 253 using a `DataView.FindRows`.

Comment: `Select` in a loop is not a good option regarding performance.

Comment: I dont think the OP is talking about a lot of rows.  S/he is implementing a form of manual Replication which is *already* suboptimal.  With a WHERE clause to limit the rows LastUpdated since the last time run, you could try to limit how many you are working with.

Comment: I using a DataSet instead of DataTable. The select method don't exists.

Comment: no, you are using the tables *inside* the DS: `ds.Tables(0)` I just reworked it to make it easier to read.  use `ds.Tables(0).Select(...`

Comment: Since [this is obviously working for you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34830545/1070452) please upvote it